# Block do not execute the way i want, lack of understanding

Tags: objective-c-blocks, game-center

I am trying to implement Game Center into my app and the code below is reporting the score.

I am trying to accomplish a solution were if the player is not authenticated it should save the score in scoreDictionary via the scoreReporter block. However, when the player is not authenticated it never hits the "If (error != nil)" statement.

As a matter of fact it passes the whole block. If the local player is authenticated it execute the block.

This is the first time i look into both Game Center and blocks in detail so i am a bit lost here.

What i want to accomplish is as described above.

I use 5.1 as target.

```
-(void)reportScore:(int64_t)score forCategory:(NSString*)category {


NSLog(@"reportScore: %lli", score);
NSLog(@"category: %@",category);


GKScore *scoreReporter = [[GKScore alloc] initWithCategory:category];
scoreReporter.value = score;

NSLog(@"scoreReporter: %@", scoreReporter);



[scoreReporter reportScoreWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"Execute the scoreReporter the block");

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                         NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *scoreFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/scores.plist",[paths
                                                                             objectAtIndex:0]];
    NSMutableDictionary *scoreDictionary=[NSMutableDictionary
                                          dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:scoreFilePath];
    if (error != nil)
    {
        //There was an error so we need to save the score locally and resubmit later
        NSLog(@"Saving score for later");
        [scoreDictionary setValue:scoreReporter forKey:[NSDate date]];
        [scoreDictionary writeToFile:scoreFilePath atomically:YES];
    }
}];
}
```

NSLog output when the player is not authenticated:

```
reportScore: 80
category: com.xxxxxx.yyyyyyyHighScore
scoreReporter: <GKScore: 0xab611b0>player:(null) rank:0 date:2012-12-19 11:18:04 +0000 value:80 formattedValue:(null) context:0x0
```

NSLog output when the player is authenticated:

```
reportScore: 60
category: com.xxxxxx.yyyyyyyHighScore
scoreReporter: <GKScore: 0x964ce30>player:G:280817155 rank:0 date:2012-12-19 11:27:45 +0000 value:60 formattedValue:(null) context:0x0
Execute the scoreReporter the block
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Game Center Programming Guide says "Most Game Center classes function only if there is an authenticated player, and those classes implicitly reference the local player. For example, when your game reports scores to a leaderboard, it always reports scores for the local player. Your game must disable all Game Center features when there is not an authenticated player."

Probably what is going on is that reportScoreWithCompletionHandler: doesn't run at all, so it doesn't "complete", so it doesn't call the completionHandler. Test for an authenticated player before reportScoreWithCompletionHandler:  GameKit code typically has several occurrences of the following if/else:

```
if ( [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].authenticated ) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```